# Excel - Indirect drop down population issue

Tags: excel, dependencies

All , I am having a problem in Excel while generating the indirect drop down. There are two drop downs (Coding , LogicCode)
[image]

Sheet1 contains the data for first drop down and second drop down values.

[image]

INT16 , INT16U are the drop down values for Coding in sheet2 . When I select INT16U the values 'Test16U' , 'TT16U' should be displayed in Logic Code drop down. The dependent values for INT16U is displayed correctly but the drop down values of INT16 is not displayed.

correct values for INT16U
[image]

Issue for INT16
[image]

The data validation part for LogicCode column is [image]

Can anyone help for this weird problem? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you create names for each of the two lists on sheet1? Propably there is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name $A$2:$A$3 on Sheet1 as "INT16" with the workbook scope. But it seems this name can't be used, so you need to change INT16 to smth. else. You can abbreviate it as INT16S, WORD, or SHORT.

[image]

**If you limited to use predefined values only, use this solution.**

Add a new row above Sheet1!A. Define names for your ranges in A row, but still use the initial range (it's $A$2:$B$2 now) as 'Coding' drop-down source:
[image]

```
Name "INT16_" = "=Sheet1!$A$3:$A$4" { Scope = Workbook; }
Name "INT16U" = "=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$4" { Scope = Workbook; }
Sheet2!C2 data validation source =Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2
Sheet2!D2 data validation source =INDIRECT(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2=C2))
```

**To set default values** e. g. on the workbook open event, add the code to ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Sheet1.[A3] = "TT"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. But , I am supposed to use the name INT16 in the drop down for my requirement. Any other options available ?

Comment: INT16 is a cell reference, so you cannot use it as a name. Perhaps prefix the names with something like an underscore and include that in the INDIRECT formula.

Comment: Similarly , the names INT64, UNICODE STRING, INT64-QUAD10K are not working. Is there any way to display INT16 in the drop down(sheet2) but rereferring in INDIRECT will refer that _name

Comment: As I am using other sheet , I used the formula as =INDIRECT(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2=C2)) . C2 is the cell where I want to populate the values in sheet2 . It says "The source currently evaluates to an error"

Comment: I added summary, it works. Check everything on your side, please.

Comment: Sorry , I am not getting the exact formulas here . Can you please provide the formulas instead of images . That would be helpful to me. Thanks again for your valuable time.

Comment: The only missing formula is the C2 data validation source '=Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2'. The D2 data validation source is as you posted in your comment.

Comment: Not sure why I am not getting the values. Still , I am getting "The source currently evaluates to an error" whenever i apply  =INDIRECT(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$2=D2))

Comment: I applied the last modification for your convenience.

Comment: Using Name Manager, check that there are no other names INT16_ and INT16U defined. Delete all others if any.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robator for your valuable timing to figure out the actual naming convention issue and  providing the solution.

Comment: Hi Rotabor, I want to select the default value in the dependent drop down . Example , In the Logic code drop down , for INT16 , TT should be selected automatically. Can you help on this ? @rotabor

Comment: Just set the target cell the desired value. Look at the modified answer.

Comment: It should be upvote.